# Pre-populate form field with data from table linked via foreign key

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

Probably a very novice Django question, but here goes. In my Django project, I have this in my models

```
#models.py
class Classes(models.Model):
        classcode = models.CharField(max_length=15)
        classname = models.TextField()
        students = models.ManyToManyField(User)

class Test(models.Model):
        classes = models.ForeignKey(Classes, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        name = models.TextField(max_length=100)
        points = models.ManyToManyField(User, default=0)
```

I also have a form for Test, which is:

```
#forms.py
class TestForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Test
        fields = ('classes', 'name')
```

When I get to the actual form, the drop-down menu for 'classes' in TestForm merely comes up with 'Classes object' for the number of 'Classes' that I have in my DB. I want to change that so the form lists the names of the classes, which are stored in the 'Classes' model as 'classname'

Can anyone point me in the right direction please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do it is to provide a string representation of your object, this would replace any where you access the class throughout your application

```
class Classes(models.Model):
    classcode = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    classname = models.TextField()
    students = models.ManyToManyField(User)

    def __str__(self):
        return "{0}: {1}".format(self.classcode, self.classname)
```

From the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/forms/fields/#modelchoicefield)

> The `__str__` (`__unicode__` on Python 2) method of the model will be called to generate string representations of the objects for use in the field’s choices; to provide customized representations, subclass ModelChoiceField and override label_from_instance.

Comment: Thanks very much for the quick and informative answer! ^^

Comment: @user2151557 - No worries, enjoy!